# Bash double quotes escape and var

Tags: bash, escaping, var, quote

I need to make a curl POST method with a JSON:

```
request=`$home/post.curl $url  " { \"name\": \"aaaaaaa\", \"message\": \"I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR \${rich_message}\" "`
```

But the server who reads the request gets `"Message=I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR "`.

Who can I do please?

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes? (Not that I fully understand neither your problem nor your question. Would you mind expanding it a bit?)

Comment: Do you want the server to receive `"message": "I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR ${rich_message}"` literally?

Comment: Yes, i want the server receive literally "message": "I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR ${rich_message}"

Answer (score 1):

If you need the entire JSON string to be passed through literally, put it in single quotes:

```
request=$($home/post.curl "$url" '{ "name": "aaaaaaa", 
"message": "I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR \${rich_message}"}$)
```

(Notice that I added the missing closing `}` and changed the obsolescent backticks to the preferred `$(...)` syntax.  I also split the string across multiple lines for legibility.  Finally, I put `"$url"` in double quotes, as this type of string should usually be properly quoted.)

If you require the entire string to be in double quotes, the syntax you were using would require an additional backslash (backticks work similarly to double quotes; you need another escape to escape the escape, as it were); but switching to `$(...)` fixes that as a side effect, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` infant of `$` is wrong. 
Also you are missing `}` at the end in order to have proper JSON.
So with proper JSON should be:

```
" { \"name\": \"aaaaaaa\", \"message\": \"I NEED TO NOT INTERPRET THIS VAR ${rich_message}\" }"
```